# Ты и ягодка? Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, тире

Он называет тебя ягодкой? Ты и ягодка? Это совсем не про тебя.

Нужны ли дополнительные знаки во втором предложении?

Может: Ты – и ягодка?

Не нужно ли кавычить слово "ягодка"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно интонационное тире для логического ударения.